# Stacking videos with ffmpeg via MATLAB not working as expected

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, matlab

I am stacking 4 video inputs in a 2x2 grid and running into a conversion failure.

Basically, at least one of the videos is just a filler black video that I generated with this line (MATLAB, hence the eval):

```
eval(['!ffmpeg -framerate 1/3600 -i black_frame.JPG -c:v libx264 -t 3600 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:240 black_frame.mp4']);
```

The other video inputs are 4 hr long videos with identical specs. I've concatenated them with this line:

```
eval(['!ffmpeg -i "' v1 '" -i "' v3 '" -i "' v2 '" -i "' v4 '" -filter_complex "  [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a0]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a1]; [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a2];  [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=qvga [a3];  [a0][a1][a2][a3]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|0_h0|w0_0|w0_h0[out] "  -map "[out]" -c:v libx264 "' output '"'])
```

When I input v1-v4 with normal videos (not the filler black video), it outputs very quickly and everything is good. The line to generate the filler black video is very fast too. But when I sub one of the video inputs with the file path for the filler black video, the speed tanks exponentially, stalls, and conversion fails.

Any pointers for me? I also tried just subbing one of the inputs with a black image file instead of generating a whole video and inputting that. But it does the same thing :/ Does it have to do with frame rate? Should I try a different approach? Thanks.

Comment: in my script, I have to use eval() to call what's inside :/ that part works! just not when I try to include the filler black videos as one of the inputs when stacking :( Is it because it has no audio or something to do with the frame rate? Idk why the speed totally drops and the file size gets massive and doesn't end up converting eventually.

Comment: Make the blank video with a sane framerate. Better yet, just set a BG color in xfade and skip the blank input.